# Send mail in php script with attachment on Ubuntu server

Tags: php, linux, mutt, mailx

I want to send a mail with attachments using php script on Ubuntu.  I have tried mutt,  mailx but they all work at local terminal when I execute them using shell_exec() they arr not working.  Plz help me

Ps :- I am beginner dnt have much knowledge about owner / permission

Comment: Google is your friend, use him.

Comment: My 2 cents - `PHPMailer`. The rest is up to you. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

I am sure, you didn't google it. There are a number of APIs that do what you need.

```
        <?php 
        //define the receiver of the email 
        $to = 'youraddress@example.com'; 
        //define the subject of the email 
        $subject = 'Test email with attachment'; 
        //create a boundary string. It must be unique 
        //so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash 
        $random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
        //define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n 
        $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com"; 
        //add boundary string and mime type specification 
        $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\""; 
        //read the atachment file contents into a string,
        //encode it with MIME base64,
        //and split it into smaller chunks
        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('attachment.zip'))); 
        //define the body of the message. 
        ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering 
        ?> 
        --PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
        Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>" 

        --PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
        Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1" 
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

        Hello World!!! 
        This is simple text email message. 

        --PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
        Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

        <h2>Hello World!</h2> 
        <p>This is something with <b>HTML</b> formatting.</p> 

        --PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

        --PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
        Content-Type: application/zip; name="attachment.zip"  
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  
        Content-Disposition: attachment  

        <?php echo $attachment; ?> 
        --PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

        <?php 
        //copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer 
        $message = ob_get_clean(); 
        //send the email 
        $mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ); 
        //if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 
        echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed"; 
        ?>
```